# Create table in mysql with data from 3 existing

Tags: mysql, crosstab

I am trying to get the column values in 'answer' in the student_answers table to be displayed in rows with the column label of associated with the 'question_id' value in questions table. I would also like the 'source_url' "date' and 'end_time' value to be in columns. The 'taking_id' value in the student_answers table = 'ID' in the taken_exams table. The taking_id is what would denote each line.

I would like a table that automatically updates with this information, but would settle for a query string.

I can't upload the questions table but is:

```
ID | exam_id | question |
1  | 1       | Gender   |
2  | 1       | Race     |
3  | 1       | Grade    |
etc...
```

There will be more questions and exams in the future so it should be dynamic.

----EDIT----QUERY----

```
SELECT answer, sa.exam_id, timestamp, sa.taking_id
FROM wp_watupro_student_answers as sa 
INNER JOIN wp_watupro_question as q 
ON sa.question_id = q.ID
INNER JOIN wp_watupro_taken_exams te
ON te.ID = sa.taking_id
GROUP BY sa.taking_id
```

[image: Results]

Comment: So basically, joining 3 tables into one with specific values from each. Keyword is "JOIN SYNTAX "

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Now how do I turn the 'answer' column into the 11 different values? Basically, I  need to transpose it first I think. All of the other questions are now missing and only the first answer is in the table. I have edited the above post to include an image.